# My ubuntu user cannot access the database created in postgres for rails by the dev user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, puma

I created a new rails project with a db user in postgres & gave that user the sufficient privileges to create a db.

After successfully running rails db:create & db:migrate , when I tried to access the webpage , I got an error that my ubuntu user "ubuntu_user" cannot access the database.

In rails 4.2, the previous project (webrick webserver) nothing like that happened , currently the project is on rails 5 with the puma webserver

Please advise.
Thanks

Note:
I got these lines in the puma webserver terminal

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-02 01:27:20 +0300 Started GET
"/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-02 01:27:20 +0300    (1.9ms)  SELECT
"schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY
"schema_migrations"."version" ASC    (13.5ms)  SELECT
"schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY
"schema_migrations"."version" ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that puma server was hanging & I had to kill it then start again.

After restarting , I got no errors.